# What is [kswapd] doing when there is no swap?

Tags: linux-kernel, swap

I have removed all swap from my testserver (i.e. it was booted with swap, swap was used actively, later `swapoff -a` was run).

Yet now and again I see `kswapd` in `top` using CPU time:

```
top - 00:53:37 up 2 days,  7:59,  1 user,  load average: 5.08, 5.07, 4.83
Tasks: 1525 total,   2 running, 1013 sleeping, 510 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.3 us, 15.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 82.5 id,  0.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
GiB Mem :    503.9 total,      2.2 free,      9.9 used,    491.8 buff/cache
GiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.    244.5 avail Mem 
Change delay from 3.0 to 
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                
    545 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  54.0   0.0  48:27.52 kswapd5                
    541 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  50.8   0.0  62:25.45 kswapd1                
    543 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  48.9   0.0  55:54.25 kswapd3                
    547 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  46.9   0.0  51:55.27 kswapd7                
    540 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  43.7   0.0  40:00.24 kswapd0                
    546 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  39.5   0.0  47:03.22 kswapd6                
2055083 tange     20   0    6704   2204   1928 S  36.2   0.0 710:01.78 paste                  
    544 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  35.9   0.0  60:54.02 kswapd4                
    542 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  31.1   0.0  60:35.09 kswapd2                
1854919 tange     20   0    6572   2080   1976 S  27.2   0.0 513:03.47 tee                    
2062582 root      20   0       0      0      0 I  21.7   0.0   0:34.20 kworker/u136:5-btrfs-+
```

It is not working constantly; it is more like a blip now and then. And it is not at 50% all the time - I just got lucky with my camera.

What is it doing?

Comment: It's managing all the swap space it has. Even though that's NONE at the moment, it could be SOME at the next check.